# Plot a series of subsetted pixels from a raster stack in R

Tags: r, stack, plot

I have created two raster stacks and would like to plot a row or column of pixels through the stack, but am not sure how to approach this.

I know I can subset by layer, but how do I subset vertically through the stack at a specific pixel location?

```
# Subsetted stack by layer
> tr_sub <- subset(tr_stack, 1:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `raster::extract` function does, and it can extract values from a stack by cell number, or x-y coordinate.

See `help(extract)` for more.